# Do you become a "Licensor" if you redistribute a work licensed under a CC 3.0 license?

Tags: creative-commons, redistribution

Alice writes a poem and licenses it under any 3.0 Creative Commons license.
Bob copies the poem and publishes it on his blog (with correct attribution).

Alice is *Original Author* and *Licensor*.  **Is Bob a *Licensor*?**

The definition says for all 3.0 licenses (e.g., [CC BY 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/legalcode)):

> **"Licensor"** means the individual, individuals, entity or entities that offer(s) the Work under the terms of this License.

How is "offer" meant here?

**If Bob is not a *Licensor*, how could he become one?**

Answer (score 5):

Paragraph 8.a of the license seems to clarify that the original Licensor [Alice], not You [Bob], is the Licensor to the recipient.

> Each time You Distribute or Publicly Perform the Work or a Collection,
>   the Licensor offers to the recipient a license to the Work on the same
>   terms and conditions as the license granted to You under this License.

You [Bob] would become a licensor if You Adapted the Work, similar to what happens in CC-BY-SA but without the restriction that you must use the same license for your Adaptor's License.

Comment: On what do you base that Bob would become a Licensor if he adapts the work? And to clarify, you mean that he would become Licensor of the adaptation, not the original work, correct?

Comment: Bassed on the slight differences between 8a and 8b.  8b says you have to "keep intact" the original copyright/license info. When you make an adaptation, copyright law says you are the owner of the copyright to any new material you have added.  Also note the slight difference between 4a and 4b (both huge walls of text).  The license doesn't explicitly say that Bob can become the licensor of the adaptation. (cc-by-sa does talk about the Adaptor's License; cc-by omits that part because it doesn't place restrictions on the Adaptor's Licens; I wish it would make that explicit)